# How select columns with UTF-8 symbols in name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis

I have **db** as a database and **"Coś ktoś_był"** as a column name in db.
I tried this:

```
  temp_df <- db %>%
      select('Coś ktoś_był')
```

but output:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Cos ktos_byl` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I don't know how make it correct without change column name.
**I can't change it!**

Comment: Use backticks ``db %>% select(`Coś ktoś_był`)``. Also, can you see the output of `names(db)`?

Comment: @DanielR names(db) works ok. I have solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
temp_df <- db %>%
  select(matches("[^ -~]"))
```

Alternatively, in `base R`:

```
db[ , grepl("[^ -~]", names(db))]
```

Both methods will select **any** column with non-ASCII characters in the name. If you need to be more specific, you can use something along these lines:

```
temp_df <- df %>%
  select(matches("^Co[^ -~]"))
```

Comment: I finally used db[,x], where x is a number of column but thanks for help, that will help me in future